# How to redirect web page from a specfic page in Sinatra?

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra

In Sinatra, how to redirect a web page from a specific page?

```
require 'sinatra'

get "/A" do
    redirect '/B' 
end

get "/B" do 
    # if comes from A
    #     "IT COMES FROM A"    
    # else not from A
    #     "NOT FROM A , REDIRECT TO C"
    #     redirect '/C'
    # end
end
```

I want to learn how to do this?

Can I use JavaScript or HTML to do what I want to do?

Or, it must be done in Sinatra?

---

I tried this, but it keeps null ,

```
get "/B" do
    mypath = URI(request.referer || '').path
    if mypath == '/A'
      "hi i am b , u come from a"
    else
      "--#{request.referrer}--"
      redirect '/C'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit! I will notice that next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information of the HTTP referrer can be retrieved via:

```
request.referrer
```

But if it is a redirect initiated by the server, it doesn't count as the referrer to the target page. In short terms:

If /A redirects to /B because the server told the client the page moved (status 302), the referrer is not /A but the page which linked to /A or nothing, if /A got requested directly.

To answer the question: You have to use client side redirecting in order to get your idea working. Javascript can do the trick (placed on /A):

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = '/B';</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check for the referrer path to do so

```
URI(request.referrer).path
```

Better approach would be to pass some parameter in the query string and you can redirect based upon its presence.

Comment: I have tried request.referer == "/A" in my if-else statement , but it did not work. How to fix it ? thanks.

Comment: I check the request.referrer , it is null.

Comment: You should extract the path from referrer. Edited the answer. It shouldn't be nil unless you're reloading the same page.

Comment: I tried your answer , but it still be nil when the referer page is /A. I  don't know the reason why. it keeps redirecting to C in code. I edited my question.