# How to redirect back to a route in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, request, sinatra

In Sinatra, how to redirect back to a route?

```
require 'sinatra'

get "/A" do
  redirect '/B' 
end

get "/B" do 
  redirect request.referer
end
```

This is the code, and I want "/B" bring me back to "/A".

Now, in browser, in "/C", send a get request to "/A". I will then go back to "/C". The reason is:
The "request.referer" is recording "/C", because the redirect in "/A" is initiated by the server, it doesn't count as the referrer to the target page.

There is a JavaScript way solving it(placed on /A):

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = '/B';</script>
```

(Got this from:[How to redirect web page from a specfic page in Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016053/how-to-redirect-web-page-from-a-specfic-page-in-sinatra#))

My question is how to redirect back to a route in server side?

Comment: use `redirect to ('/some_route')`. or enable session/cookies, set referrer information, then access it and use redirect to ('/referrer_route')

Answer (score 6):

Just say `redirect back`.  From [the Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) (scroll down to "Browser Redirect"):

You can also easily redirect back to the page the user came from with redirect back:

```
get '/foo' do
  "<a href='/bar'>do something</a>"
end

get '/bar' do
  do_something
  redirect back
end
```

Comment: Is `back` a method in Rails, or does it need to be a symbol (`:back`)?

Comment: In sinatra it's a method, I'll add rails info later.

Comment: I apologize.  I totally missed that this is a Sinatra question.